# Is it possible to create a port based ingressroute in k8s?

Tags: kubernetes, heptio-contour

I have a Debian k8s cluster. I need to route all traffic from http://*fqdn_of_my-service* to *pod_my_service:8080* and route https://*fqdn_of_my-service* to *pod_my_service:8443*. 
(fqdn_of_my-service and pod_my_service are in both cases the same) 
To put it simple, I just need to split traffic based on ports for one service. Is there any way of doing it?

Comment: Which ingress controller are you using?

Comment: So for default Kubernetes ingress specification it looks not possible. https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.17/#ingressrule-v1beta1-networking-k8s-io ("The `:` delimiter is not respected because ports are not allowed. Currently the port of an Ingress is implicitly :80 for http and :443 for https. Both these may change in the future.")